# Put data into temp table on linked server

Tags: sql

I have two servers (f.e. A and B)

Server A has linked server B, but server B doesn't have linked server A

I need to create stored procedure on server A, which: 
1. Create temp table on server B
2. Put data from server A to temp table on server B
3. Exec merge-instruction on server B using this temp table on server B as source and normal table on server B as target
4. Drop temp table from server B

I can't find decision how to create temp table on linked server and put data from local server to this table
I tried to do it using Exec .. at, but server B knows nothing abount server A

Comment: did you try  table variable?

Comment: Please take a look at this article for better results on this site:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here are a few sources to get you going in the right direction. You did not state what SQL environment you are using so I'm kinda guessing here. [StackOverflow on creating a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126382/stored-procedure-and-populating-a-temp-table-from-a-linked-stored-procedure-with). [Syntax on how to connect to a non-linked DB](http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/connect-to-remote-database-without-a-linked-server/).

Comment: If all the work is basically on B, why are you running the process from A?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?