# CTE & Temp Tables Performance Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, temp-tables

The query that I've been working on for awhile now was filled with 7 Temp Tables until I had to replace them with CTE's (7 CTE's) due to OPENQUERY giving the following error when using TempTables:

> Metadata discovery only supports temp tables when analyzing a single- statement batch.

When I run the Query with Temp Tables, the run duration is:
`7:50`

When I run the Query with CTE's, the run duration is:
`15:00`

Almost double the time! Is there any other alternative to OPENQUERY that might make it run faster while perhaps keeping my temp tables?

Current execution Query:

```sql
SET @XSql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([server], ''' + REPLACE(@QSql, '''', '''''') + ''')'
EXEC(@XSql)
```

I used this for reference: [Stored Procedure and populating a Temp table from a linked Stored Procedure with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126382/stored-procedure-and-populating-a-temp-table-from-a-linked-stored-procedure-with)

And need a optimal solution.

Open to suggestions!

Comment: OPENQUERY works with temp table with no issues. I have changed quite some queries with heavy CTEs to use temp tables due to performance issue.

Comment: @PeterHe Can you perhaps show an example of using a temptable while using OPENQUERY? I have several of them though...

Comment: After read the below answer, I realized i misunderstood your question. I thought you used temp table outside of the sql send to the remote server. For your question, if you have complex logic on the remote side, its better to create a stored procedure and deploy to the remote server. Your OPENQUERY just call that SP.

Comment: Are you using the tem table the same way as the link? Then my original understanding was right. You need to add quotes in the parameter

Comment: @PeterHe The Query that I'm working on is a Stored Procedure which needs optimizing due to the high run-time. All my temp tables and my final select statement are quoted out to then be ran into OPENQUERY with the linked server. If that makes sense.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @PeterHe Do you know a site where I can paste it as it's too long to paste it here?

Comment: Try http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `EXEC ... AT SERVER`? This worked fine for me:

```
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE #TestTable1 (ID int); CREATE TABLE #TestTable2 (ID int); SELECT * FROM #TestTable1, #TestTable2;') AT LinkedServer;
```

Comment: This does not help at all in my case.

Comment: Why not @LifeOfJona ? if you don't give a why, we can't help you more.

Comment: My tables are already pre-made. I cannot be creating new tables whilst executing my query.

Comment: How are temporary table premade? Temporary tables only exist in the context of the session they are **created** in. either you aren't using temporary tables, which means that the description of your scenario is wrong, or your statement above is. Which is it?

Comment: I attached a link for reference which I have been using. Please take a look at that as that is what I'm trying to achieve but something that'd work in my case.

Comment: I got rid of the creating temp tables in between and just used the "EXEC AT" and it worked just fine for me. Thanks again.